# Plugin.Geolocator not Available

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-play

I have a strange behavior.
I'm creating an xamarin.forms solution using the Montemagno Geolocator plugin. https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin. In debug mode everything is fine.

I have this API configuration:
"Compiled Used Android Version: API27",
"Minimun Android to Target: API21".

If I put "Target Android version: API27" the plugin geolocator always returns me error 'not Available'.
If I put "Target Android version: Use Compile using SDK version" everything is ok but Google Play Store does not accept it because from August 1st it wants at least API26.

where is the error?

Comment: You probably want to look into this: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/ it includes the geolocator and is maintained past the separate Geolocator plugin.

Comment: Did you add permissions to access location ?

Comment: I think I have given all the permissions, but at this point I have some doubts. Yet I checked several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by introducing a few lines of code to manage the permissions using the plugin 'Plugin.Permissions'. The fact remains that, until a few weeks ago everything worked smoothly without the aforementioned plugin.
For the code, see the example in the plugin https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE************

I read the interesting article of montemagno https://blog.xamarin.com/android-apps-google-play-target-api-level-requirements/

So I updated vs2017 to the latest release, I have updated all the nuget packages included: Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps, Plugin.CurrentActivity, Xam.Plugin.Geolocator, Xam.Plugin.Media.

Montemagno say "These must be set to a specific version and cannot be set to “Use Compile Version”, but, in my smartphones, the locator only works if I use the setting “Use Compile Version”. If I use montemagno settings, I get locator.IsGeolocationAvailable = false!!

it work if i use android:targetSdkVersion="25"...

Comment: I have updated everything, visual studio, NUGET, Android SDK. Now I have the problem on the Android emulator with target API27. If I set the target to "Use Compile Version" (i use SDK API27), geolocator will work but Play Store will not accept the APP for the new policy ...